Convergence of $ \vec{x_{n+1}} = A^{-1} f(\vec{x_{n}},\vec{y_{n}}), \:\:\: \vec{y_{n+1}} = A^{-1} g(\vec{x_{n}},\vec{y_{n}}) $
I have two systems
$$ A \vec{x} = f(\vec{x}, \vec{y}), \:\:\: A \vec{y} = g(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) $$
Both have same constant, square matrix $A$. I implemented an iterative algorithm with an initial value of $\vec{x_{0}}, \vec{y_{0}}$. Then
$$ \vec{x_{n+1}} = A^{-1} f(\vec{x_{n}},\vec{y_{n}}), \:\:\:  \vec{y_{n+1}} = A^{-1} g(\vec{x_{n}},\vec{y_{n}}) $$
And it turns out that they are always convergent when I compute in Matlab, for a particular matrix $A$.
Is there a theorem that specifies the necessary and sufficient conditions for the convergence?
I know only that for $A \vec{x} = \vec{b}$, we need to find a matrix $P$ and constant $\vec{p}$ such that
$$ \vec{x} = P \vec{x} + \vec{p} $$
and then the iterative
$$ \vec{x_{n+1}} = P \vec{x_{n}} + \vec{p} $$
convergent when the spectral radius of $P$ is less than 1.
